# React Three Fiber curve-based animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-three-fiber, animejs

I was just wondering if is it possible to use a library like [tween](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/) or [animejs](https://animejs.com/) to increment a value in a curve-based

With that I meant to increment a value from n to x using an [easing curve](https://animejs.com/documentation/#linearEasing).

My ultimate goal is to make like a acceleration animation to the camera so I would like to use like a "ease-in-out" CSS equivalent animation.

I tried to use anime.js to increment a [property of an object](https://animejs.com/documentation/#JSobject) and then update the position of the camera

```js
const animRef = useRef(null);
let animValue = {
  value: 0,
}

useEffect(() => {
    animRef.current = anime({
      targets: animValue,
      value: 10,
      easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
      autoplay: false, // So I can use a custom RAF loop
      update: function (anim) {
        // animValue.value <- here the value is updated
      },
    });
})

useFrame(({clock}) => {
    // Using a custom RAF loop
    animRef.current.tick(clock.elapsedTime)
    // animValue.value <- Here the value is always 0
    cameraRef.current.position.z += animValue.value
})
```

but the value property wont be incremented, the tick call is working but it is not updating the object property outside the `anime.update` function.

If there's another way approach my goal I will gladly listen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use anime, gsap etc. react-spring would probably be better. gasp/anime, watch out how you store their handles and anim-objects. local state is always kept in `useState(() => new Foo())`. other than that, the easiest is lerp/damp, because they're inbuilt in threejs.

```
useFrame(() => {
  ref.current.opacity = THREE.MathUtils.lerp(ref.current.opacity, condition ? 1 : 0, 0.1)
```

as for your code, you will loose references. state inside the render function will be lost next render. use useref or usestate. i have never tried anime before but you have to take into consideration that a component re-renders, as in, it's called multiple times.

```
const x = useRef({ value: 0 })
useEffect(() => {
  anime({ targets: x.current, ... })
}, [])
```